# Export Visual Studio test results in some document / report format?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, export

It is possible to export/print Visual Studio test results in some document format, maybe including test details?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know MSTest all too good, but you can run the Visual Studio tests via the Gallio framework (which is free, you can get it [here](http://www.gallio.org)), and that gives a very nice (and very detailed) test report.

HTH!

Comment: I'm testing Gallio, that would be good, but it is not working both in the Icaro gui or in visual studio with resharper, issuing BadImageFormatExceptions.

Comment: Ups, never heard about this issue. I'm sorry for you. Maybe you can submit an issue to the Gallio dev team, they're usually quite responsive.
I personally am working with Gallio+MbUnit+R# for almost three years now, and I never had serious problems...

Comment: I'm searching for a some how to for Gallio, but no luck. I've simply loaded the test dll assembly generated by visual studio in Icarus, and after pressing play, i get a "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."